# display blage page after publish in host

Tags: .net-core, visual-studio-2019, publish, http-error

i have a project by .net core 2.2 and use visual studio 2019 for publish it.

project works locally without any problems, but when I upload it and put it on a host it shows a blank page. And in system logs,show HTTP ERROR 500

where is problem?